# Unnecessary definition of resource in Google's Android Notepad tutorial?

Tags: android

I am learning Android from Notepad tutorial and one thing confuses me. Since Notepad2 in file notes_list.xml is used + with definition of id resource:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
<TextView android:id="@+id/android:empty"
```

But from what I have read + sign is nnecessary  only when defining new resource and list and empty is not new, but it is provided by android. So why did they used + sign then? If you delete program runs anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably habit or copy/paste. :)

You're correct in that you don't need it, the `@+id/` syntax will define a new id if one with that name didn't already exist. Since the Android framework ids `android.R.id.list` and `android.R.id.empty` exist as part of the public SDK the two forms are functionally equivalent here. It's slightly better for clarity/style to omit the + for framework ids since it avoids the confusion shown here.